# Add Item to Finder Sidebar

Tags: macos, cocoa, plist, macos-carbon, finder

I would like to add a new item to the Finder sidebar. I found out that the Finder keeps the list of "places" in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist. I was able to read the file using Carbon API and saw that each item had Name, icon and alias.

Using a 3rd party application such as PlistEdit Pro I was able to update the alias. My question is how to update the alias using Carbon API. Was not able to find a way to create alias that will open in Finder. It seem that both Dropbox and PlistEditor Pro was able to find the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Carbon/RN-LaunchServices/index.html):

> The Shared File List API is new to
>   Launch Services in Mac OS X Leopard.
>   This API provides access to several
>   kinds of system-global and per-user
>   persistent lists of file system
>   objects, such as recent documents and
>   applications, favorites, and login
>   items. For details, see the new
>   interface file LSSharedFileList.h.

You want to look for the key kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, which handles the items under "Places" in the Sidebar.
I guess you could try to do something similar to [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pyobjc/pyobjc-26/pyobjc/pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices/PyObjCTest/test_lssharedfilelist.py), using LSSharedFileListCreate to create kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems.

Or you could use the applescript posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540557/add-an-item-to-the-finder-save-dialog-sidebar), which would be way easier, but not the "Right Way"©

Comment: @amitp Great! I guess could select my answer as solution then! :-)

Answer (score 3):

***Update for 2015***

The `LSSharedFileList` header says this has moved to the [CoreServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreServicesReferenceCollection/) framework. In fact, if you Cmd-Shift-O (in Xcode) and type LSSharedFileList, then navigate to the only result, you'll see in the jump bar that the header is indeed now contained within `CoreServices.framework`. In any case, the key is still `kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems`.

Example:

```
+ (BOOL)appendFavoriteItemWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

  // Pessimism ...
  BOOL result = NO;

  // Do we have a file URL?
  if (url.isFileURL) {

    // Ask CoreServices for the favorite items list 
    // (kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems)
    LSSharedFileListRef list = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);
    if (list) {

      // We've got the list, so try to append our item
      // (use kLSSharedFileListItemBeforeFirst vs. 
      // kLSSharedFileListItemLast if desired)
      LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(list,
                                     kLSSharedFileListItemLast,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     (__bridge CFURLRef)url,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL);

      // Did it work?
      if (item) {

        // Release the item and flag success
        CFRelease(item);
        result = YES;

      }

      // Release the list
      CFRelease(list);

    }

  }

  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
// Create the path to the favorite item to add
NSString * itemPath = [@"~/Music" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSURL * itemURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:itemPath];

// Insert the item
[WhateverClassTheAboveFunctionIsIn appendFavoriteItemWithURL:itemURL];
```

Comment: I created this Gist that wraps this functionality into a simple NSURL category: https://gist.github.com/jnozzi/817f3276c55dbb7025be

Comment: Up-voted, I like this solution, but its a shame that some of those functions are now deprecated on 10.11. Any idea what to use instead?

Comment: Not at the moment, Ben. Are the deprecated methods annotated in the headers? They may suggest the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

@Asmus : By default 'command + T' is the shortcut to add a folder to sidebar in finder.  Applescript pointed by u is working fine when keyboard shortcut key 'command + T' is assigned manually to other tasks.

> The applescript fails if executed after setting 'command + T' as the shortcut key to show my other desktop in osx lion(10.7)

**Update 2023:** Due to the availability of Tabs in Finder and other applications, `command + T` creates a new Tab. The new default shortcut is **`command + ctrl + T`**!