# How to obtain IconRef from Application Resources

Tags: macos, finder

I want to add custom place to Finder Favorites sidebar using LSSharedFileList API as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517874/programmatically-add-a-folder-to-places-in-finder). But I need to add a custom icon to this item. The icon should be in the `IconRef` type. I have not found a way to do it. Found only a [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062856/how-do-you-programmatically-put-folder-icons-on-the-finder-sidebar-given-that-y) of the fact that the need to use Icon Services. But how?

Comment: If you will set folder icon using [[NSWokspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:someIcon forFile:someFile options:0]; that will appear in finder sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function of [Scplugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/).

```
static IconRef IconRefFromIconFileNoCache(CFStringRef file)
{
    IconRef iconRef;
    IconFamilyHandle iconFamily;
    FSRef fileRef;
    CFURLRef url;
    Boolean ok;

    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL,file,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,false);
    if (!url)
        return 0;

    ok = CFURLGetFSRef(url,&fileRef);
    CFRelease(url);
    if (!ok)
        return 0;


    if (ReadIconFromFSRef(&fileRef, &iconFamily))
        return nil;

    iconRef = 0;
    HLock((Handle)iconFamily);
    GetIconRefFromIconFamilyPtr(*iconFamily,(**iconFamily).resourceSize,&iconRef);
    DisposeHandle((Handle)iconFamily);

    return iconRef;
}
```

Comment: If one happens to have an `NSURL*`, one can cast that as `CFURLRef` and pass it to `CFURLGetFSRef`.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately not suitable for use with `LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL` on Mac OS X >= 10.7